# How to increase the request size limit using minimal api with .NET 6?

Tags: asp.net, .net, minimal-apis

I have an endpoint to upload videos

```
app.MapPost("/video/upload", async (HttpRequest request) =>
```

It works with small videos but when I try to upload a video of larger size I get an error saying that I exceeded the allowed size

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature`

```
async (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    var bodySizeFeature = 
    request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>();
    if (bodySizeFeature is not null)
    {
        bodySizeFeature.MaxRequestBodySize = 10; // set limit or null for unlimited
    }
        
    // process request
}
```

Comment: This does not work if the uploaded file is bound directly as a parameter of the minimal api delegate like `app.MapPost("upload", (IFormFile file, HttpRequest request) { ...your code from above }`

Answer (score 1):

We can configure kestrel through the builder value and specify the max request body size

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(o => o.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null);
```

`null` means that there is no limit.

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured in the `web.config` file.

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This will set the limit to 1GB

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but web.config only works with IIS server. I'm under Linux / macOS